# Can't parse date using datefns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have the following date =>

`October 16 at 6:24 PM`

I would like to parse this date into a Javascript Date Object using dateFNS

I tried to follow the doc and did

`dateFns.parse(stringDate, 'MMMM d [at] h[:]mm a..aaa', new Date())`

but it always return me `Invalid Date`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ts9uub?file=index.ts

am I using it wrong ?

Comment: `a..aaa`? what's that?

Comment: I think that  means `a` or `aa` or `aaa` - I couldn't make your code work for anything without a year ... until I used the **latest** version of date-fns (i.e. 2.16.1 as opposed to 1.29.0 that you're using)

Comment: it looks like you're trying to use v2.x parse method, but loading 1.x version of datefns - parse did not look like that at all in 1.x

Comment: @JaromandaX  https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format its supposed to be AM or PM

Comment: I am using npm version 2.16.1 maybe the fiddle is outdated  I will check

Comment: i updated the exenple

Comment: use `a`, `aa`, or `aaa` ... not `a..aaa` - you've misunderstood the documentation .... so ...  use `let parsedDate = parse(stringDate, "MMMM d 'at' h':'mm a", new Date());` - that will work - note the `''` instead of `[]` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
parsedDate = parse(stringDate, "MMMM d 'at' h':'mm a", new Date());
```

The documentation states that for AM/PM use `a..aaa` ... this actually means use 1, 2 or 3 `a` for AM/PM ... then there's `aaaa` and even `aaaaa` I think ...

Also `[at]` should be `'at'` etc

Comment: and the `a..aaa`

Comment: It would be good if this answer could be expanded to say when you might want to use 1, 2 or 3 `a`s - i.e. does `a` do something different to `aa`?

Comment: The documentation and this answer is clear @Dezza `a`, `aa` and `aaa` produce AM or PM - you can use 1, 2 or 3 `a` and produce the same result